# castle nh facility - 2 databases / 2 models / 2 factories

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility, facilities

I have asked this on the castle list as i'm using the nh facility but it just dawned on me to ask it here too :)

sorry for the cross posting.

I'm using the nh facility to configure the following setup:

i have 1 database which stores generic report configuration.
and another which stores the actual report data.

i also have 1 project for interacting with the report configuration
database (entities and mappings etc)
and another for interacting with the report data database  (entities
and mappings etc).

i've used the following to create 2 factories:

```
<facilities>
  <facility id="nhibernate">
    <factory id="nhibernate.factory.session1">
      ...
      <assemblies>
        <assembly>ReportData.Model</assembly>
      </assemblies>
    </factory>

    <factory id="nhibernate.factory.session2" alias="reporting">
      ...
      <assemblies>
        <assembly>Reporting.Model</assembly>
      </assemblies>
    </factory>
  </facility>
</facilities>
```

the problem is is that even though nhibernate.factory.session1 and
nhibernate.factory.session2 are looking at different databases and
have different assemblies configured it always seems to create the
tables for both models in both DBs?

how do i tell nhibernate.factory.session1 to look at db1 and model1
and nhibernate.factory.session2 to look at db2 and model2?

cheers

w://

Comment: cross-posted at http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/6d3fba13c545f5c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution here is to not use fluent when doing tackling complex scenarios.